# Equilateral triangle packing in the $l^1$ circle v.s. the $l^2$ circle

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, discrete-geometry, packing-problem

As established in a previous post [Equilateral Triangles In The Taxicab Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086545/equilateral-triangles-in-the-taxicab-space) there are exactly $8$ equilateral triangles (of edge length $1$) that can be packed in the $l^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ unit circle, while there are only $6$ equilateral triangles (of edge length $1$) that can be packed in the $l^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ unit circle.

My suspicion is that if one were to consider an $l^{1 + \epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ unit circle, then for sufficiently small epsilon, the number of equilateral triangles which can be packed in the unit circle is still $8$. More so, I suspect that for a specific value of $\epsilon >0$ the $l^{1+ \epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ unit circle can only contain $7$ equilateral triangles.

Question 1: Is my suspicion correct?

Question 2: Is there a value $\epsilon >0$ such that the $l^{1+ \epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ unit circle contains exactly $7$ equilateral triangles?

Comment: Perhaps an easier question to consider might be worth approaching. Notice that in the Taxicab space, $l^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, one can pack exactly 4 circles of radius $1/2$ inside the circle of radius $1$. For the usual Euclidean space, one can only pack $2$ circles of radius $1/2$ into the the circle of radius $1$. Does there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ so that the $l^{1+\epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^2)$  unit circle contains only $3$ circles or radius $1/2$ ?